# Batch database table data insert using MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, insert, mysql-error-1064, bulkinsert

I'm uploading multiple entries into a table in our database using MySQL. However, the following command does not work and throws up this error "**#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**"... which is odd as there are 4 columns as included below:

*(I've just included two of the results here as an example of the data)*

```
INSERT INTO state (state_id,country_id,state_name,active) VALUES (152,153),(5),(Test1,Test2),(1)
```

This should form multiple rows and eventually look like this:

state_id | country_id | state_name | active
152          5            Test 1         1
153          5            Test 2         1

(that looks like a table in the edit... but not rendered on here, sorry!)

Comment: Do you want to insert more than one row? In which column are the two values `(152,153)` supposed to go?

Comment: Yes, multiple rows. I should have specified that. So in the end it should look like the edit above

Comment: See my answer on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert multiple rows, you need to supply the correct number of values for each row.

The syntax is such that you specify one row after the other, not columns:

```
INSERT INTO state 
(state_id,country_id,state_name,active) 
VALUES 
(152,5,'Test1',1), 
(153,5,'Test2',1);
```

Answer (score 1):

After VALUES you also have to put groups of 4 values if you defined 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO state (state_id,country_id,state_name,active) VALUES ('(152,153)','(5)','(Test1,Test2)','(1)')
```